# Is there a connection between Affront, Effront, Effrontery?

Tags: etymology

From the Oxford Dictionary

> **Affront**
>   An action or remark that causes outrage or offence.

Effront is not in any of the major modern dictionaries including the Oxford dictionary, however it is cited in wiktionary from the 1913 Webster's dictionary as

> **Effront**
>   To give assurance to.

Effrontery is listed in the modern day Oxford Dictionary as well as other dictionaries

> **Effrontery**
>   Insolent or impertinent behaviour.

I came across this word as a crossword answer for the clue *Brass Neck* which made me assume that *Effrontery* was the action of *Effronting* or performing an *Effront*. However it does not seem to be the case and the historic definition of *Effront* appears to be something else entirely. I would not have been surprised to have seen the definition of *Affront* appearing as the definition for *Effront* because they seem connected.

Are these words all related somehow? I could not find much about the etymology.

Edit:

Thanks for the link to etymonline I haven't come across that before. It explains that there was an *Effront* but it disappeared. It says to compare *Effrontery* with *Affront* but it offers no explanation of how it came to be. Looking up *Affront* on there shows *Related: Affronted; affronting.* but no *Affrontery* and the meaning is worded differently perhaps they are considered interchangable.

I would like to know how we ended up with some words beginning with A and some beginning with E and why there are certain variations that do not exist in each set. Seems strange.

Comment: Please include the research you've done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. The Online Etymological Dictionary is considered a general reference work.

Comment: The definition *to give assurance to* is not in the OED, which has two definitions: *To free from bashfulness* (a backformation from *effronted*) or *To put to confusion.* Maybe *to give assurance to* somehow came from *to free from bashfulness*.

Comment: According to the OED, the word *effronted* means *Shameless, barefaced, unblushingly insolent*, and it comes from French *effronté*. The word *effront* in English seems incredibly rare.

Answer (score 3):

According to the OED, the word *effront* is a backformation from *effronted* (which used to be an English word) and means:

> 1. To free from bashfulness,
> 2. To put to confusion.

In the 1911 Webster's dictionary on Google books, I find the second definition, as well as:

> 3. To give assurance to.

The verb *effront* is incredibly rare; nearly all the hits in Google books are misspellings of *affront*. I suspect that it has mainly been used by people who guessed at its meaning by knowing the meaning of the adjective *effronted*, and not by people who learned its meaning from hearing or reading it.

The word *effronted* used to be a real English word, and according to the OED it means:

> Shameless, barefaced, unblushingly insolent.

So what would *effront* mean, if it's a backformation from *effronted*? It's what you have to do to somebody to make them *effronted*. What would do this isn't clear at all.

So would all three definitions of *effront* above, if done to somebody, result in them being *shameless, barefaced, unblushingly insolent?*

I think so, although it's only clear for the first definition. For the second definition, somebody who is confused and scared might lash out and be unblushingly insolent. For the third definition, if you gave assurance to somebody that their actions would have no consequences to them, they might become shameless or unblushingly insolent.

The adjective *effronted* comes from the French adjective *effronté*, which also does not appear to have a corresponding verb. And *effronté* comes from the Latin word *effrons*, which also gave us *effrontery*.

Literally, the Latin word *effrons* means *without a forehead*. Why that should mean *shameless* is not entirely clear. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effrontery) gives two possible explanations. One of them is:

> Some explain that "frons" can also refer to the capacity for blushing, so a person without "frons" would be "unblushing" ...

The word [*affront*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/affronter) comes from the French verb *affronter*, meaning *to confront, to face*. This comes from Old French *afronter*, whose construction would literally mean "to slap on the forehead", but which *le trésor de la langue français informatisé* says also meant "to shame" and "to confront".

So *effronted* and *affronted* in common have the root *front*, meaning *forehead* in French. It's possible that the word *front* was a metonym for *blush* in the etymology of both of them—so the etymology of *effronted* would be *unblushing*, while *affront* would be *to cause to blush* (one of its early meanings was *shame*; the other *to slap in the face.*).

Answer (score 0):

The connection is the term ***[front](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=front&allowed_in_frame=0)***: late 13c., "forehead," from Old French front "forehead, brow" (12c.), from Latin frontem (nominative frons) "forehead, brow, front; countenance, expression ***(especially as an indicator of truthfulness or shame).***

(Etymonline)

***[Effrontery:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effrontery)***

> - To the Romans, the shameless were "without forehead," at least figuratively. ***Effrontery derives from Latin effrons, a word that combines the prefix ex- (meaning "out" or "without") and "frons" (meaning "forehead" or "brow")*** .
> - The Romans never used "effrons" literally to mean "without forehead," and theorists aren't in full agreement about the connection between the modern meaning of "effrontery" and the literal senses of its roots.
> - Some explain that "frons" can also refer to the capacity for blushing, so a person without "frons" would be "unblushing" or "shameless." Others theorize that since the Romans believed that the brow was the seat of a person's modesty, being without a brow meant being "immodest," or again, "shameless."

(M-W)